# JAVA converting from String to Binary and then back to String in file

Tags: java, string, file-io, character-encoding, binary

I want to read text from file which is `"Hello"` and then I want to convert this text to corresponding Binary form like:

`01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111`

Now, I after binary conversion, I want to again convert the same

`01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111`

to `Hello` and write it to file

And How can the same be done for multiple words like "Hello World my name is XYZ"

How can I possibly do that? Please help

Comment: Have a look at Integer.toString(...), Integer.parseInt(...), String.getBytes(...), and the String(byte[],...) methods and constructors.

Comment: @GregS `BitSet` could also be deployed on the result of String.getBytes, if direct programmatic bit access is required. There must be some use case for that class?

Comment: learn how to divide and multiply by 2... and learn how to read and write files byte by byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didnt go into detail on how to read/write files, since you can look that up. However, to achieve what you want:

- you will need a method to convert a word to binary
- then you will need another method to convert from binary to words

below is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   File file = new File("input.txt");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
   String word=sc.nextLine();
   String receivedBinary=stringToBinary(word);
   System.out.println();
   String receivedWord=BinaryToString(receivedBinary);
 }
 public static String stringToBinary(String text)
 {
     String bString="";
     String temp="";
     for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
     {
         temp=Integer.toBinaryString(text.charAt(i));
         for(int j=temp.length();j<8;j++)
         {
             temp="0"+temp;
         }
         bString+=temp+" ";
     }

     System.out.println(bString);
     return bString;
 }
 public static String BinaryToString(String binaryCode)
 {
     String[] code = binaryCode.split(" ");
     String word="";
     for(int i=0;i<code.length;i++)
     {
         word+= (char)Integer.parseInt(code[i],2);
     }
     System.out.println(word);
     return word;
 }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit of a shame that `Integer.toBinaryString` doesn't always print all bits of a byte, maybe you should subroutine that. `word+= (char)Integer.parseInt(code[i],2);` doesn't feel correct.

Comment: right, didnt notice, just added some padding so it will always show 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

OK, because I like puzzling and because the Java language could have more support for this kind of low level array operations. I've coined the term bitgets to indicate the character representation of a 0 and 1, and a method `toBitgets` to print all 8 bits of a byte.

This class also uses some regex fu to make sure that the parsed string has the exact representation that was requested of it: 8 bitgets followed by a space or the end of the input.

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class S2B2S {

    public S2B2S() {

    }

    public void toBitgets(StringBuilder sb, byte b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE; i++) {
            sb.append('0' + ((b >> (Byte.SIZE - i - 1))) & 1);
        }
    }

    public String encode(String s) {
        byte[] sdata = s.getBytes(US_ASCII);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sdata.length * (Byte.SIZE + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < sdata.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
            byte b = sdata[i];
            toBitgets(sb, b);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String decode(String bs) {
        byte[] sdata = new byte[(bs.length() + 1) / (Byte.SIZE + 1)];
        Pattern bytegets = Pattern.compile("([01]{8})(?: |$)");
        Matcher bytegetsFinder = bytegets.matcher(bs);
        int offset = 0, i = 0;
        while (bytegetsFinder.find()) {
            if (bytegetsFinder.start() != offset) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            sdata[i++] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(bytegetsFinder.group(1), 2);

            offset = bytegetsFinder.end();
        }
        if (offset != bs.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return new String(sdata, US_ASCII);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello";
        S2B2S s2b2s = new S2B2S();
        String encoded = s2b2s.encode(hello);
        System.out.println(encoded);
        String decoded = s2b2s.decode(encoded);
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one debug run was required, I'm getting good at this :)